# Can mod_python respond to /user/123/doc/456/ style URLs?

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

We're using mod_python for most of our scripts.  Now we're being asked to implement an API that accesses URL's like:

```
http://example.com/app/user/123/doc/456
```

We'd like to handle this in our existing framework.  But usually `mod_python` is invoked like:

```
http://example.com/app?user=123&doc=456
```

Is there a way to handle `/user/123/doc/456` style URLs in mod_python?

Comment: Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: A example mod_python function could be `def index(req, user, doc)` where the framework puts the value of the HTTP GET or POST parameters in the Python function parameters

Comment: You are really asking about routing dynamic urls to requests as seen in flask, Django, Pyramid, etc.  While you can code this in python it has already been done.  Consider flask with mod_wsgi or a simple Django app.

Comment: @fiacre: I agree, but I'm looking for a short term solution here, which would not require an Apache config change.